# Draw a Hilbert curve by recursion

Tags: java, recursion, turtle-graphics

I need to draw hilbert curve at sixth order, but my programm works only for first order. I think something is wrong with rotation (or everything), but what exactly? Will be very appreciated for your help.

```
public class TurtleFractal {

public static void HilbertCurve(int n, Turtle fred, double step) {
    if (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            fred.left(90);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.forward(step);
            fred.right(90);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.forward(step);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.right(90);
            fred.forward(step);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.left(90);
        } else {
            fred.right(90);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.forward(step);
            fred.left(90);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.forward(step);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.left(90);
            fred.forward(step);
            HilbertCurve(n - 1, fred, step);
            fred.right(90);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Turtle fred = new Turtle(0, 0, 0);
    //fred can go forward or turn to any angle
    // 0,0-initial coordinates, 0-angle
    fred.down();
    int n = 2;
    //n - curve size 

    double s = Math.pow(2, n - 2);
    double step = 0.5 / (s * 3 + (s - 1));

    //draw the curve
    HilbertCurve(n, fred, step);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fractal code bifurcation in `HilbertCurve()` looks good, so I'm guessing the problem has to do with your computation of `step` in the `main()` method.

Here's a different approach where I've used `worldCoordinates()` to change the coordinate system to match the problem (otherwise you need to know the size of the window -- something you left out of your `step` calculation.)  I also coalesced the halves of `HilbertCurve()` into one by passing an angle value of 90 or -90 instead of branching off the parity of `n`.  (Just for variety.)

Your turtle library is different from the one I found so you will need to adjust the code accordingly.  You should state where you got your turtle library when asking a question like this.

```
public class TurtleFractal {

    public static void HilbertCurve(int n, Turtle turtle, double angle) {
        if (n <= 0) return;

        turtle.left(angle);
        HilbertCurve(n - 1, turtle, -angle);
        turtle.forward(1.0);
        turtle.right(angle);
        HilbertCurve(n - 1, turtle, angle);
        turtle.forward(1.0);
        HilbertCurve(n - 1, turtle, angle);
        turtle.right(angle);
        turtle.forward(1.0);
        HilbertCurve(n - 1, turtle, -angle);
        turtle.left(angle);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double s = Math.pow(2, n);
        Turtle fred = new Turtle();

        fred.worldCoordinates(0, 0, s, s);
        fred.up();
        fred.goTo(0.5, 0.5);
        fred.down();
        HilbertCurve(n, fred, 90.0);
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
> java TurtleFractal 4
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]